# In Linux, is 'make folder/path/clean' same as running 'make clean' command in folder/path?

Tags: directory, make

I'm new to Linux, more so for Makefile.

In Linux, is 'make folder/path/clean' same as running 'make clean' command in folder/path/?

(folder/path/ refers to an arbitrary directory.)

Apart from this question, is there a generalization one can make about this syntax (of command and argument) in Linux?

Update based on comments and suggested answers:
Thanks, I learned some new things. I also found that Makefile that I am using (openwrt) is different from the normal GNU Makefile in that it has more features.

A summary is that that the two commands in the main question are not the same.

Comment: Linux, is the OS kernel found in a number of Operating systems like Debian, Ubuntu, ArchLinux... Is your question about building Linux in those OSes, or about using `make` when building any particular software in any particular Operating System built around a Linux kernel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To execute `make clean` in `folder/path`, you want

```
make -C folder/path clean
```

The `-C` switch is not POSIX, though (see the comments). It works, at least, for GNU `make`, which is the `make` you have if you're running Linux.

Comment: The `-C` option [is not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html).

Answer (score 6):

No it is not. Your syntax would not work unless you have a rule for `folder/path/clean` in the directory that you execute the `make folder/path/clean` in.

You can, for example, make a recursive clean rule in your make file to (maybe?) achieve what you want. For example:

```
recursive-clean:
  (cd folder/path; make clean)
  ...
```

For each directory that you have or just do a for loop over all the directories etc.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. If not, let me know and I can update my answer).